# Importing multiple .csv files into R adding condition (row.names=1)

Tags: r, read.csv

Have find original question and solution here:
[Importing multiple .csv files into R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433432/importing-multiple-csv-files-into-r)

solution is:

```
temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
list2env(
  lapply(setNames(temp, make.names(gsub("*.csv$", "", temp))), 
         read.csv), envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

but I want to add one condition to `read.csv`, `row.names=1` --the first column is row name
then the solution does not work anymore. Any suggestion?

was using:

```
temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
list2env(
  lapply(setNames(temp, make.names(gsub("*.csv$", "", temp))), 
         read.csv(row.names=1)), envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call a function using `lapply`, you don't write arguments in braces as you would when you call the function itself. Instead, just add the argument like:

```
list2env(
  x = lapply(
    X = setNames(temp, make.names(gsub("*.csv$", "", temp))), 
    FUN = read.csv, row.names = 1
  ), 
  envir = .GlobalEnv
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use this general syntax for `lapply`:

```
lapply(df, function(x) read.csv(x))
```

In other words, you may specify an anonymous function to be applied to `df`.  Applying this to your actual code:

```
temp <- list.files(pattern=".csv")
list2env(lapply(setNames(temp, make.names(gsub(".csv$", "", temp))),
    function(x) read.csv(x, row.names=1)), envir = .GlobalEnv)
```